# When will this site graduate out its "Public Beta" state?

Tags: discussion, beta

It's great that the site has graduated to Public Beta, but what does that imply?

When will it graduate out of its beta state? Are there new thresholds which we need to reach?

Comment: There is no major benefit from graduating out of public beta. It literally just removes the "Beta" string from the logo and changes reputation privileges. It does not look like custom logos and themes are coming anymore. Ethereum has been waiting for five years now since graduation.

Comment: In the same direction as this post, now that we are in Public Beta, what are the things we should be watching out for? Is there a way that we fail the Public Beta phase and lose this site?

Comment: @q9f: Ethereum no longer has to wait :)

Answer (score 5):

Our most recent guidelines for leaving beta are outlined in the MSE post - [Congratulations to the 59 sites that just left Beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/374096/congratulations-to-the-59-sites-that-just-left-beta).

To quote that:

> For the sites that are leaving Beta today, the following criteria were determined:
>
> - The site needed to be in public Beta for at least six months
> - The site needed to have at least 1000 open questions
> - At least 70% of the questions on the site needed to have at least one upvoted answer

In addition, we like to see that the site has put some effort into defining their scope by creating help page content for their [On Topic help center page](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as well as having discussion about site curation, scope and moderation on meta.

It seems like y'all really like specific targets for things and I understand that but... in general, leaving beta isn't really considered a big thing here. Many of our sites spend years in "beta" not because they're ill-defined but because our definitions for beta have been changing significantly to be more loose than prior years, which required huge (and often unattainable) activity targets like having 10 questions per day.

Very little changes when a site leaves beta. At this point, it's just a new election and the removal of the word "beta" from the logo. So, don't fret too much and, instead, focus on making a site with great content that's useful to the Substrate/Polkadot community.